# How do I add an OR function to a PHP code?

Tags: php

Firstly, dont laugh, I know it is basic.

I have this code: `if ($pageid == '9') { echo...` and I want to add an OR to it, so I tried: `if ($pageid == '9' or '5') { echo...` but it didnt work. How do I add an OR function to this?

Comment: You already got a good answer from Tatu Ulmanen. I just wanted to add that you can also use the `or` operator: `if ($pageid == '9' or $pageid == '5') { echo...` . Maybe it would feel more natural to you.

Comment: Cheers Alin! that is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ($pageid == '9' || $pageid == '5') { echo...`

Note that if you have a large number of pageids to check for some reason, you can utilize arrays:

```
if(in_array($pageid, array(9, 5, 3, 12, 5)) { echo ...
```

`or` works instead of `||` also but `||` is more commonly used.

Comment: And if I want to add three, then do I do this: if ($pageid == '9' || $pageid == '5' || $pageid == '2') { echo... ?

Comment: Cheers. Ive selected your answer as the one :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention another approach that makes use of PHP's [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array) - it's quite handy if you've a few values you want to treat as a cluster that don't justify a switch but would be painfully verbose to use a traditional or for.

```
if(in_array($pageID, array(1, 2, 3))) {
   // Do exciting things...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($pageid == '9' || $pageid == '5')
```

Comment: And if I want to add three, then do I do this: if ($pageid == '9' || $pageid == '5' || $pageid == '2') { echo... ?

Answer (score 1):

this should work too. i am not sure why this won't work in your case

```
if($pageid == "9" OR $pageid == "5"){
 echo "pageid ".$pageid;
}
```

for more information see this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($pageid) {
    case '5':
    case '9':
        echo "...";
    break;
    default:
        // Do something useful
    break;
}
```

This is useful, if you have more than one cases, because it prevents you from ugly "elseif"-chains. Also if you have one case with many different values its more readable and its easy to add additional values. You just need to add a new `case 'xy':` line.